# Account linking with Actions SDK?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I'm trying to require account linking with Actions SDK, but all the documentation I can find only tells you how to do it with Dialogflow.

I've filled in the OAUTH implicit grant fields in Actions Console > Overview > Account linking.  However, when I attempt to use my action, I never get the link behavior.

Google support doesn't even seem like they understand the question.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action.json file, you will have a [top-level object](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/ActionPackage) named `accountLinking`. [In this object](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AccountLinking), you'll include the client id and secret that Google will use when connecting to the OAuth endpoint, what type of OAuth flow you're using, scopes the Assistant should be requesting, and so forth.

So your action.json might include something like this:

```
{
  "manifest": {
    ....
  },
  "accountLinking": {
    "clientId": "unique-client-id",
    "clientSecret": "donttellanyonebutmoresecurethanthis",
    "grantType": "IMPLICIT",
    "authenticationUrl": "https://login.example.org/oauth/v2/authorize",
    "scopes": ["profile","email"],
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: A combination of this plus the `signInRequired` in the actions was the ticket.  Thanks!